# Application_Start dose not run after take a publish from project

Tags: asp.net

I have tried for many times to run application after I had take a publish. but it dose not work.Or in an other word `Application_start` does not run,
I corrected it by add this line in `Application_start` Method in Global file:

`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

after this adding this line `Application_start` runs.

but I don't know why it's working????

Comment: What's not working, the application or your call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` ?

Comment: My application dose not work

Comment: Is there any reason why you have put `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break`?

Comment: No there isn't . If you put this `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` and run it works well.after run if you delete this `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` again it works. I don't know why. may be running app by `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` for one time is enough to fix app and you can delete  `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break`

Comment: It works well with and without that line? So where's the issue?

Comment: after publish app does not work => I add this line code => app runs well => after run , I stop app and delete this line => but app again work. just this and I don't know why. I have never seen any sample like this.

Comment: With, and without the `Debugger.Break` line? Have you checked your Event Viewer?